# don't apply css styles in django

Tags: python, django

Yesterday i was working on a Django-project: added css rules and all worked, but today all stay ass yesterday, but css rules don't apply=(

Everything was fine yesterday, but nothing is applied this morning.
Today all stay as yesterday, but css styles do not apply

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Css/style.css' %}">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header style=" background-image: url({% static 'Img/1.jpg' %})">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1><span class="wel">Wel</span><span class="come">come</span></h1>
            <h3><em class="a">to the best site in the World!</em></h3>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the css code:

```
* {
    font-family: arial, helvetica
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.intro {                        # This i want to change
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.wel {
    color: #8495E1
}

.come {
    color: #C886A5
}    

.a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0F1D37;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh (Cltr F5)?

Comment: no, it is should be try in server or in code?

Comment: wooow, thx, it works! You the best

Comment: You're welcome! Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/13290801